# Reactor Kafka: Consumption is stopped without any explicit errors

Tags: spring-kafka, reactor-kafka

We have seen issues intermittently where one of our application nodes stops consuming messages, thereby building up consumer lag in a few of the Kafka topic partitions. Eventually, all of our application nodes stop consuming messages, and consumer lags build up on all of the partitions.

At this time, we have verified that at the Kafka broker, our consumer threads were reported to be alive and healthy. When we restart one of the nodes, all the other nodes that are not consuming messages start consuming messages again. When we check the logs in these nodes, we see a message **Attempt to heartbeat failed since the group is rebalancing**, which indicates rebalancing and assignment of new partitions.

The theory we have so far is that due to transient network exceptions, the consumer gets into a state where the consumption is paused indefinitely, but the heartbeat is successful. Is this a possible scenario? We weren’t able to reproduce this behavior locally.

The exception that is seen before the consumption is stopped:

2022-09-23|05:41:55.414 DEBUG r.k.r.internals.ConsumerEventLoop - thread=reactive-kafka-runtime-processor-1 correlation_id= tid= provider_id= entity_type= userid= realmid= Resumed

2022-09-23|05:41:56.835 DEBUG r.k.r.internals.ConsumerEventLoop - thread=reactive-kafka-runtime-processor-1 correlation_id= tid= provider_id= entity_type= userid= realmid= Emitting 1 records, requested now 1

2022-09-23|05:41:56.835 DEBUG r.k.r.internals.ConsumerEventLoop - thread=reactive-kafka-runtime-processor-1 correlation_id= tid= provider_id= entity_type= userid= realmid= onRequest.toAdd 1, paused false

2022-09-23|05:41:56.835 DEBUG r.k.r.internals.ConsumerEventLoop - thread=reactive-kafka-runtime-processor-1 correlation_id= tid= provider_id= entity_type= userid= realmid= Paused - too many deferred commits

2022-09-23|05:41:56.835 DEBUG r.k.r.internals.ConsumerEventLoop - thread=reactive-kafka-runtime-processor-1 correlation_id= tid= provider_id= entity_type= userid= realmid= Consumer woken

2022-09-23|05:42:13.082 INFO  o.a.k.clients.FetchSessionHandler - thread=reactive-kafka-runtime-processor-1 correlation_id= tid= provider_id= entity_type= userid= realmid= [Consumer clientId=consumer-runtime-processor-1, groupId=runtime-processor-prd] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=214139410, epoch=1) to node 208:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null

2022-09-23|05:42:18.097 INFO  o.a.k.clients.FetchSessionHandler - thread=reactive-kafka-runtime-processor-1 correlation_id= tid= provider_id= entity_type= userid= realmid= [Consumer clientId=consumer-runtime-processor-1, groupId=runtime-processor-prd] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=973107219, epoch=1) to node 308:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null

2022-09-23|05:42:21.106 INFO  o.a.k.clients.FetchSessionHandler - thread=reactive-kafka-runtime-processor-1 correlation_id= tid= provider_id= entity_type= userid= realmid= [Consumer clientId=consumer-runtime-processor-1, groupId=runtime-processor-prd] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1457615640, epoch=INITIAL) to node 107:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null

There are no logs for the next couple of hours until the restart of a different node. Restart causes the below logs to appear, and the consumer starts consuming messages again:

2022-09-23|07:39:20.019 INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - thread=reactive-kafka-runtime-processor-1 correlation_id= tid= provider_id= entity_type= userid= realmid= [Consumer clientId=consumer-runtime-processor-1, groupId=runtime-processor-prd] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing

**Reactor kafka version:** 1.3.11

**Auto Acknowledge with maxDeferredCommits were set.**

our consumer function looks like below:

```
public Flux<Message<String>> consumeRecords() {
    return reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate
      .receiveAutoAck()
      .doOnNext(t -> log.info("On Next call from customer template"))
      .doOnComplete(() -> log.info("On Complete call from customer template"))
      .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
      // rate limit flow to start processing n events every t time duration where:
      //   t - is given by kafkaConsumerRateLimitConfig.getDurationInMillis()
      //   n - is given by kafkaConsumerRateLimitConfig.getConcurrency()
      .flatMap(x -> Mono.just(x)
          .delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(1000)),
        1
      )
      .flatMap(consumerRecord ->
        Mono.just(consumerRecord)
          .map(kafkaRecordMapper::mapConsumerRecordToMessage)
          // handle error
          .doOnError(t -> {
            log.error("AutoAck Exception occurred when consuming kafka consumer record", t);
          })
      )
      .doOnError(throwable -> Mono.just(throwable)
        .doOnNext(t -> log.error("AutoAck Kafka consumer template failed -", t))
        .subscribe()
      )
      .retryWhen(Retry.indefinitely())
      .repeat();
  }
```

**KafkaReceiver Properties**

Below are some of the properties we have explicitly set.

```
auto.commit.interval.ms = 1000
auto.offset.reset = earliest
heartbeat.interval.ms = 1000
security.protocol = SSL

with maxDeferredCommits set to 200
```

Properties with defaults printed in splunk:

```
allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 1000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = consumer-consumer-kafkaretry-2
    client.rack = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = consumer-kafkaretry
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 1000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = SSL
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = /app/resources/kafkatruststore.jks
    ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
```

Comment: `Paused - too many deferred commits` is the smoking gun; please edit the question to show your complete receiver options.

Comment: @GaryRussell I have updated the question with receiver options

Comment: I don't see you using `acknowledge()` or `commit()` on the `ReceiverOffset` - using deferred commits does not make any sense in that case.

Comment: @GaryRussell We are not manually acknowledging as of today. I have a couple of questions: 
1. We haven't seen this issue occurring after we set the maxDeferredCommit to 0. So is this property associated with manual acknowledgment and not auto Acknowledge? If it was for manual commit, shouldn't the property be ignored when used for auto Acknowledge and not cause the consumer pause issue?
2. Can a similar consumer pause issue happen if the maxDeferredCommit > 0 is used with manual acknowledgment?

Comment: Yes, it should be ignored if you are not using manual commits; it was not designed for auto commit; please open an issue on GitHub. It can only happen with manual commits if you fail to acknowledge/commit that many offsets..